# jquery check if img has src

Tags: jquery, image, src

I have a carousel of images that are dynamically populated. There is potential for up to 5 images, however, if there is less than 5 images I need to introduce some if statements in my code. Is it possible using jQuery to check if an img src is blank?

For example, if I have an image with class "optional" but it has no url, is there a way to detect this with jQuery?

```
<img class="optional" src="" />
```

Comment: Do you want a selector that will find ones with empty src attributes, or do you want to parse all relevant images and run an if statement against them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.optional').each(function () {
    if (this.src.length > 0) {
        //if it has source
    }
});
```

Comment: can I do src.length == 0 instead of > 0 so that I have a statement if it has no source?

Comment: @SamSkirrow yes you can

Answer (score 9):

You can use attribute selector:

```
$('img.optional[src=""]');
```

In case that you want select the images that don't have empty `src` attributes:

```
$('img.optional[src!=""]');
```

Comment: `$('img.optional[src=""]')  ` to be more exact

Answer (score 3):

```
if($.trim($(".optional").attr("src")) != "")// check image has src
{
// do your stuff
}
else{
}
```

reference **[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** and **[trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)**

Answer (score 2):

JQUERY :

```
if($('img.optional').attr('src') != "") {
  // Image has src !
} else {
  // Image has not src :'(
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
img[src=""] {
   display: none;
}
```

The above selector will simply match, if the src attribute has no value.